# Allow multiple iTerm2 window

Tags: osx, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 with XtraFinder. XtraFinder allow you to open a terminal in the current folder.

In version <= 2.1.4, it works great.

When I upgraded to version 3.0.9, it never opens a new iTerm2 window.

Instead, it activates the iTerm2 window, no new tab, no new window, so it's not functioning at all.

Anyone know how to fix that?